# show values of a long list in jsp using pages

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, struts, paging

Hi I need to show a long list of values using jsp, I am wondering how to have paging, so a number of values be shown and use paging to view other pages such as following:

```
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  Next
```

Answer (score 3):

The [display tag library](http://displaytag.sourceforge.net/11/) has the [`<table>`](http://displaytag.sourceforge.net/11/displaytag/tagreference.html#table) tag, that can be used to display paginated data. [Install](http://displaytag.sourceforge.net/11/install.html) it and just use `<table>` with the `pagesize` attribute to define the number of elements in every page.

For instance, if `myAction.do` is the action that gets the data and shows the JSP the `<table>` is in, and `data` is the `List` of data, and assuming the elements in the `List` have a field named `someColumn`:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://displaytag.sf.net" prefix="display" %>
...
<display:table pagesize="5" id="table" name="data" requestURI="myAction.do">
    <display:column property="someColumn" title="Column 1"/>
</display:table>
```

Here is a simple tutorial showing pagination : [Struts2 Pagination Using Display Tags](http://www.devmanuals.com/tutorials/java/struts/struts2/Struts2Pagination.html)

Comment: Seconded. It also lets you sort by clicking on the table header, and it can work with AjaxAnywhere to use Ajax for loading pages.

Comment: Thanks for your answers guys, do you have any other sample code? I need to show a couple of things in each cell, but it seems it has specific value for each column. I want to make it like having a name, family and age of each person in each cell.